# How to covert linear gradient from css to linear gradient in react native?

Tags: css, react-native

I have a linear gradient in css `linear-gradient(315.43deg, #706EB6 -6.67%, #A57FCF 106.6%)` and i want to use with the component [`LinearGradient`](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient) in react native. What are the equivalents of `start`, `end` and `locations` props and How can i pass from linear gradient in css to react native ?

Answer (score 1):

In React Native you can use colors property like this

```
<LinearGradient colors={['transparent', '#000000']}>
</LinearGradient>
```

In the same way, you can pass the start, end positions

You can see the props of LinearGradient here

```
declare module 'react-native-linear-gradient' {
  import * as React from 'react';
  import * as ReactNative from 'react-native';

  export interface LinearGradientProps extends ReactNative.ViewProps {
    colors: (string | number)[];
    start?: { x: number; y: number };
    end?: { x: number; y: number };
    locations?: number[];
    useAngle?: boolean;
    angleCenter?: {x: number, y: number};
    angle?: number;
  }

  export class LinearGradient extends React.Component<LinearGradientProps> {}

  export default LinearGradient;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But how can i pass from linear gradient in css to react native  ?

Comment: @AbdoRabah We can't do this in React-native. CSS is used on the web. In the mobile apps, you have to use the alternate methods provided